# "Collecting package metadata: failed" with UnavailableInvalidChannel error when conda install in a brand new Anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Just after I successfully installed Anaconda in Windows (using [the official installer](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)), I tried to install a package with `conda` command. Then, I got the following `UnavailableInvalidChannel` error:

```
C:\Users\user>conda install numpy
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: pkgs/msys2/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs
  channel url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs
  error code: 404
```

It seems `conda` is using wrong channel url, but there is no reference to `https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs` in my config.

```
C:\Users\user>conda config --show channels
channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/
  - defaults
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem?

Here is my environment:

```
C:\Users\user>conda info

     active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\user\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\user\.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.11
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\user\.conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.11 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: If you install anaconda, numpy is default installed?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Yes. My point is why `Collecting package metadata` fails. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: After I removed `https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/` & `https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/` from my channels, everything is going well. Thank you anyway.